# Magento - Configurable products issue

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Please check below screenshot showing in admin for configurable products for specific skus.

After page view, the source is giving the following errors.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in <b>/var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Grid.php</b> on line <b>245</b><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

As I researched about  your error, a product attribute might be cause of this error.

To find out that attribute you need to go to error file --

> app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Super\Config\Grid.php

and dump the product attribute code like below before this line `$productAttribute->getSource();` at line 245 --

> var_dump($productAttribute->getAttributeCode()); die("stop");

once you find out that product attribute, disable that attribute and then check your product edit page.

I hope it would help you to find out the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by following reasons.

```
1. Attribute assigned to simple/child products.
2. Attribute not assigned to configurable products.
```

`Resolved by assigning missing attribute to configurable products in attribute sets`.